# Apiary Proxy Request Timed Out

Tags: apiary.io, apiary

I'm trying to use Apiary to document my API and test requests but I keep getting a response 504 Proxy Request Timed Out. 
My API is running on my machine under http://localhost:3000/ and I specified that under the HOST metadata. 
When I click compare under the call, it shows that Apiary added a header "host" that specifies a user specific proxy. 
Is there something I am missing or does Apiary just not like localhosts?

Answer (score 3):

Because the proxy remotely calls your specified HOST, you cannot directly call localhost. You could could use https://ngrok.com and set up a tunnel and use the tunnel URL as the HOST.